# Django's CreateView Multiple Forms

Tags: python, django

I have two `CreateViews` client and company. I am trying to add a client from the company create page. I thought i would just be able to change the `action` in the form tag to point to the client url. Nothing happens though when i click submit.

urls.py

```
url(r'^clients/create/$', ClientCreate.as_view(success_url="/app/clients/"), name='clients-create'),

url(r'^company/create/$', CompanyCreate.as_view(), name='company-create'),
```

views.py

```
class ClientCreate(CreateView):
    model = Client
    fields = [...]

class CompanyCreate(CreateView):
    model = Company
    fields = [...]
```

create-company.html

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
    <a (Link to popup form)>+</a>
    <form role="form" method="post" action="client/create/">{% csrf_token %}        </form>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the logic to create the client? or to associate it to a company? you should also have a models.py

Comment: If this is your template, than reason is that you simply [can't have nested forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms).